# Android MenuItem & new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

The case for MenuItem:

```
case MENUITEM_LISTA: Toast.makeText(this, "Lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent lista = new Intent(this, ListaCompletaActivity.class);
            startActivity( lista ); 
        return true;v
```

The ListaCompletaActivity.class:

`public class ListaCompletaActivity extends ListActivity {`

DDMS Error:

```
11-15 09:47:11.274: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-15 09:47:11.274: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1314): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When i try the code of ListaCompletaActivity.class in new project, the code run.
Maybe the bug is in the new Intent().Can you help me?

Comment: A bit more of the logcat would help :)

Answer (score 0):

change intent with this

```
Intent lista = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ListaCompletaActivity.class);
 startActivity( lista );
```

Comment: The same error:11-15 10:23:12.094: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bansiamo.lib/bansiamo.lib.ListaCompletaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerExceptions are usually the easiest to fix. Please read the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629974/content-provider-in-android-sdk-in-eclipse/7656005#7656005) post.

> The null pointer exception usually means something is not
>   instantiated. Debug, and step through to check your variables up to
>   this line. You are referencing something null.